# Checking if today is a Wed or Sat with java.util.Calendar

Tags: python, date, calendar, compare, jython

I have a stax doc with some embedded scripting to check if today's day is a Wed or Sat, after initial formatting the correct day is printed to screen but in the find() method "Wed" is always printed to screen, even on a Sat. Is there a better way to do this compare?
jython code can be run within the script

```
import java.util.Date
import java.util.Calendar
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

now = java.util.Date()
dayFormat = java.text.SimpleDateFormat('EEE')
cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();  
cal.setTime(now);  
cal.add(java.util.Calendar.HOUR, 5);
dayBeforeFormat = cal.getTime();

day = str(dayFormat.format(dayBeforeFormat))
print(day)


if day.find('Sat'):
    print('Sat')
elif day.find('Wed'):
    print('Wed')
```

Comment: Hey how exactly did you write this code? How did you call the java classes into python?

Comment: Have you tried `day.equals("Sat")`?

Comment: its actually jython Tabish, updated question. Get an error using `day.equals("Sat")` .. AttributeError: 'string' object has no attribute 'equals'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the code runs on a Saturday, the value of `day` is "Sat" and this bit:

```
day.find('Sat')
```

returns 0. This is the lowest index in the `day` string where the substring "Sat" is found. See http://www.jython.org/docs/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods.

0 is equivalent to boolean `False`.

This will work:

```
if day.find('Sat') > -1:
    print('Sat')
```

Or simpler:

```
if day == 'Sat':
    print('Sat')
```